# No connection to Google Compute engine instance after upgrading on advice google team

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I resize instance from 4 cpu to 2, after this, server not responded, SSH connection timeout to instance.

I cannot understand why this problem occurred, and how to solve it.
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that you've followed documentation [Changing the Machine Type of a Stopped Instance](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/changing-machine-type-of-stopped-instance) and after that your VM instance is running, but you're not able to connect via Cloud console web interface and via Cloud Shell with a [command](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/ssh) `gcloud compute ssh`.

Please restart your VM instance, if it's possible, and check logs at `Compute Engine` -> `VM instances` -> click on NAME_OF_YOUR_VM -> at the `VM instance details` find section **Logs** and click on `Serial port 1 (console)` for any error or warning messages that could explain what happened to your VM instance.

After that, please have a look at the documentation [Troubleshooting SSH](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-ssh) and follow the instructions. You'll be able to choose appropriate action after checking console log at the previous step.

Also, you can connect to your VM via [Serial console](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/interacting-with-serial-console) by following this [guide](https://medium.com/google-cloud/resolving-getting-locked-out-of-a-compute-engine-85800251890b), but keep in mind that:

> The interactive serial console does not support IP-based access
> restrictions such as IP whitelists. If you enable the interactive
> serial console on an instance, clients can attempt to connect to that
> instance from any IP address.

more details you can find in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/interacting-with-serial-console).

If nothing helped, please add full console log to your question by using [hastebin.com](https://hastebin.com/) or other similar service and describe which steps you've done so far by following [Troubleshooting SSH](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-ssh) guide.